# Get image folder path based on relative path with Jquery or PHP

Tags: php, jquery, path

There is an image inside HTML page. I use Jquery for 360 grad rotation. My Jquery plugin gets the list of all images via AJAX request. But the problem is, that I don't know where the user will locate scripts ang images.

For example images will be located at home/mypage/public_html/gallery/pictures/ and scripts at home/mypage/public_html/scripts/rotate/. I have an option for user to show the path to scripts and want the script to get images path automatic, based on first image path.

For example I have some image with relative path:

```
<img src='pictures/001.jpg'>
```

url is: mypage.com/gallery/pictures/001.jpg

How can I get a path to containing folder in form:

home/mypage/public_html/gallery/pictures/

It's no matter to do it with Jquery or PHP

a PHP script then loads all images from home/mypage/public_html/gallery/pictures/

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src='<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/gallery/pictures/001.jpg'>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

In the end it depends on whether you process your data on the server side (PHP) or on the client side (JavaScript), but you need to use the getcwd() PHP function:

http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

So you can pass the relative image path to PHP through jQuery, and then append the current working directory (getcwd) to the beginning.

Comment: There is an image inside HTML page. I use Jquery for 360 grad rotation. My Jquery plugin gets the list of all images via AJAX request. But the problem is, that I don't know where the user will locate scripts ang images. For example images will be located at home/mypage/public_html/gallery/pictures/ and scripts at home/mypage/public_html/scripts. I have an option for user to show the scripts path and want the script to get images path automatic, based on first image path.

Comment: but how can i get the relative path (not from src attribute, but from page root) with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: yes, i've tryed it $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/showroom/example/'.$imagedir; but how can i get the '/showroom/example/' part with a script?

Answer (score 0):

Path of `mypage.com\` plus `gallery\pictures` plus `Image name`